# Changing style with JQUERY is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the following code to change style on my menu, but it's not working, what's wrong my code?

```
<script>



$(".menu-superior .submenu li").mouseover(function(){
$(this).css('color' , 'white' );
});

$(".menu-superior .submenu li").mouseout(function(){
$(this).css('color' , 'black' );
});


</script>
```

PS: before anyone asks, there's a reason why i'm not using CSS, let's just leave it at that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks syntatically valid.  Did you try logging the .length of your selectors to make sure your matching elements?

Comment: Post your `html` code

Comment: Have you got any errors in the console? I mean, jQuery is def included.

Comment: no reason that adding class would make it work when it wasn't before

Comment: @Taplar I used alert to verify it, and it worked, i think there's something wrong with the .css part.

Comment: Can we see a fiddle with the entire code in action?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are attaching the listeners before the DOM is fully loaded.  Place your code inside $( document ).ready() and try.